# oracle 12c sqlplus login error subscriber

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sqlplus

I am facing below error/warning when I login to oracle 12 using sqlplus client.

### Details :

> SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Nov 8 05:38:11 2019
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> subscriber -1581956048 create failed: Last Successful login time: Fri
>   Nov 08 2019 05:36:31 -05:00
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release
>   12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

---

Not sure what is **subscriber -1581956048 create failed**  not getting much info on Google.

is anything need to worry about?

Regards

Laks

Answer (score 1):

> Issue caused by `Fast Application Notification` (`FAN`) for `OCI` client.
>
> `FAN` uses `Oracle Notification Services` (`ONS`) to publish and subscribe
>   service for communicating information about all `Fast Application Notification` (`FAN`) events.
>
> `ONS` uses port `6200` by default. If there is a firewall between the
>   client and the server and port `6200` port is closed then this behavior
>   is expected

You can use `OCI` to access `Oracle TimesTen In-Memory Database` and `Oracle TimesTen Application-Tier Database Cache`. `OCI` is an API that provides functions you can use to access the database and control SQL execution. OCI supports the data types, calling conventions, syntax, and semantics of the `C` and `C++` programming languages.
TimesTen and TimesTen Cache support `the Oracle Call Interface` (`OCI`) for `C` or `C++` programs.

Starting with `Oracle Database Release 12c Release 1` (`12.1`), Oracle provides an `oraaccess.xml` file, a client-side configuration file. You can use the `oraaccess.xml` file to configure selected `OCI` parameters (some of which are accepted programatically in various `OCI` API calls), thereby allowing `OCI` behavior to be changed during deployment without modifying the source code that calls `OCI`.

Updates to the `oraaccess.xml` file will not affect already running clients. In order to pick up any updates to the `oraaccess.xml` file, already running clients need to be restarted.

The `oraaccess.xml` file is read from the directory specified by the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable in regular and instant client installations.

This is the `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` directory on `UNIX` operating systems and the `%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN` directory on `Microsoft Windows` operating systems, if `TNS_ADMIN` is not set in regular client installations.

The `oraaccess.xml` file has a top-level node  with the three elements. One of them is . the  tag allows specifying default values for various `OCI` parameters. Some parameters can only be specified once and hence apply to all connections. These global parameters are described using by some tags. One of them is `<events>` tag.
<kbd>[Ref .](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci10new.htm#LNOCI80678)</kbd>

If you already have an `oraaccess.xml` file, then convert the part 
`<events>true</events>` to `<events>false</events>`.

Otherwise create an `oraaccess.xml` file with the following information in the **default_parameters** section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" ?>
<oraaccess xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oci/oraaccess" 
           xmlns:oci="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oci/oraaccess" 
           schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oci/oraaccess
http://xmlns.oracle.com/oci/oraaccess.xsd">
<default_parameters>
    <events>false</events>
</default_parameters>
</oraaccess>
```

put this file under `TNS_ADMIN` directory, and then restart the `SQL*Plus Client`.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros Ozhan.. I will check with our team about firewall.